# htaccess redirect from top to subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a web server with the following (simplified) layout:

```
/
    www/  # will hold html and PHP files (web content)
    doc/  # some documentation
    lib/  # some libraries
```

I would like to use *htaccess* to "redirect" every request to *www.mydomain.com/page* to *www.mydomain.com/www/page.php*.

I have tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1.php
```

But it produces a *500 Internal Server Error*.

For debugging purposes, I created a *www/test.php* page which echoes every GET variable, and I modified my *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/test.php?page=$1
```

just to check whether I'm matching the right things.
The expected behaviour when performing a request against *www.mydomain.com/somepage* would be *page=somepage*, instead I get *page=www/get.php*.

Why this behaviour? How can I accomplish what I need?

Comment: If you encounter an internal server error, always consult the log file. Always. In this case it would have hinted to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude the path you are rewriting to :

```
RewriteRule ^((?!www).*)$ www/test.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

otherwise you will get an infinite loop error because **www/test.php** also matches the rewrite pattern **(.*)**

Comment: Additional information: It only stops rewriting it the url stays the same after trying to apply all rules. In the second case, `www/test.php?page=www/test.php` rewrites to the same url.

Comment: That worked, now it makes sense to me. It was an infinite loop I didn't think of.